# Bot With dynamic choices doesn't display merge field values

Tags: einstein-bots

The Merge field value in dynamic choices is not getting displayed, here how its coming , The number of records in List Are getting displayed properly but its not displaying the field data.

[image]

following is flow config

[image]

Following is bot config

[image]

I have assigned list data through flow action.I even tried action type as flow to directly get dynamic choices from flow, even that didn't worked

Answer (score -1):

It seems i Missed Permission for the field.

Comment: Can you expand on this a little? Presumably it was field level security? It's all good to answer and accept your own answer (have to wait a couple of days to do that) but it helps the community more if you can include as much detail as possible.